# Python sum elements between two numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, range

I'm sure this is very simple. I've searched google and here and not found the specific answer

```
a = rnd.randn(100)
print np.sum(a)
```

gives sum of elements in a

```
np.sum(a[a>0.])
```

gives sum of elements greater than 0

```
print np.sum((a < 2.0) & (a > -2.0))
```

ok so this returns the number of elements between 2 and -2.

how do I get the sum of the elements between2 and -2??? I've tried lots of things for example

```
np.sum(a[a >0.] & a[a<1.])
```

etc and can't find the correct way to do it :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is a bitwise operator and doesn't give you the proper result, instead you need to use `np.logical_and` to get a mask array. Then you can pass it as the index to the array in order to get the desire items, then pass it to the `sum`:

```
In [9]: a = np.arange(-10, 10)

In [10]: a[np.logical_and(a>-2,a<2)]
Out[10]: array([-1,  0,  1])

In [11]: a[np.logical_and(a>-2,a<2)].sum()
Out[11]: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in just in a very basic direct way, something like:

```
function getSum(numArray, lowVal, highVal):
    mySum = 0
    for i in range(len(numArray)):
        if(numArray[i] >= lowVal and numArray[i] <= highVal):
             mySum = mySum + numArray[i]

    return mySum

yourAnswer = getSum(a, -2, 2)
```